# Jenkins - shell script - find parameter format not correct

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, path-finding, rollbar

[image]
hope one of you can help - I'm running a script in jenkins pipeline, so that I can upload source maps to rollbar, so I need to loop through the minified js files - I'm trying to do this with the FIND command but it keeps giving me an error: **find parameter format not correct** - script below:

```
stages {
    stage('Set correct environment link') {
        steps {
            script {
                buildTarget = params.targetEnv
                if(params.targetEnv.equals("prj1")){
                    linkTarget = "http://xxx.xxx.xx/xxx/"
                } else if(params.targetEnv.equals(.......)..etc.
    stage('Uploading source maps to Rollbar') {
        steps {
                sh ''' #!/bin/bash
                    # Save a short git hash, must be run from a git
                    # repository (or a child directory)
                    version=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)

                    # Use the post_server_time access token, you can
                    # find one in your project access token settings
                    post_server_item=e1d04646bf614e039d0af3dec3fa03a7

                    echo "Uploading source maps for version $version!"

                    # We upload a source map for each resulting JavaScript
                    # file; the path depends on your build config
                    for path in $(find dist/renew -name "*.js"); do
                      # URL of the JavaScript file on the web server
                      url=${linkTarget}/$path

                      # a path to a corresponding source map file
                      source_map="@$path.map"

                      echo "Uploading source map for $url"

                      curl --silent --show-error https://api.rollbar.com/api/1/sourcemap \
                        -F access_token=$post_server_item \
                        -F version=$version \
                        -F minified_url=$url \
                        -F source_map=$source_map \
                        > /dev/null
                    done 
                '''
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
        steps {
            echo 'Deploying....'
```

From Bash CLI
[image]

Comment: Please post the error message. Also you've a shell script. Not a bat script. Please change the title.

Comment: Does the same command works from a bash command line? You could check if jenkins uses a different `find` command (`which find`)

Comment: when I run the script from the the bash CLI -  I keep getting
curl failed to connect to api.rollbar.com port 443 timeout 
I've tried to use the: post_server_item and post_client_item access tokens in the script

Comment: but yeah the find command works in bash CLI

Comment: Have you confirmed that both `dist` and `dist/renew` are valid paths, and that they are present where the script is running?

Comment: @ShaneBishop yes when I run it on cli it loops through the .js files

Comment: @jeb see updated question with screenshot from bash cli and ran the (which find) command from the cli and get this: $ which find
/usr/bin/find - not sure how to run/check this on jenkins But it does seem to be the issue i.e. jenkins is running the windows version of FIND

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of @jeb I managed to resolve this FIND issue on jenkins by placing the absolute path for (find) in the shell script - initially it was using the windows FIND cmd, so i needed to point to cygwin find cmd

**before**: for path in $(find dist/renew -name "*.js"); do

**and after**: for path in $(/usr/bin/find dist/renew -name "*.js"); do

Thaks to all that commented